# Две лишние запятые

Tags: javascript, html, dom

В `body` должен появится див с `textContent = Заголовок`. Но почему-то появляется `Заголовок,,`.

```js
class Modal {
  constructor() {}

  createModal(...args) {
    const modal = document.createElement('div');
    args.forEach((el, i) => {
      const item = document.createElement('div');
      item.classList = 'item';
      if (i === 3) {
        item.innerHTML = el;
      } else {
        item.textContent = el;
      }
      modal.appendChild(item);
    });
    document.body.appendChild(modal);
  }
}

class NewModalWindow extends Modal {
  constructor({
    title = 'Заголовок',
    description = '',
    content = ''
  }) {
    super();
    this.title = title;
    this.description = description;
    this.content = content;
  }

  a() {
    super.createModal(Object.values(this));
  }
}

const a = new NewModalWindow({}).a();
```

```html
<body></body>
```

Comment: Потому что внутри массива `args` лежит ещё один массив `['Заголовок', '', '']`. Соответственно, внутри forEach переменная `el` это тоже массив, и браузер пытается его преобразовать в строку, а при преобразовании массива в строку его элементы перечисляются через запятую. У вас в массиве три элемента — поэтому появились две запятых. Второй и третий элементы этого массива это пустые строки — поэтому две запятые слиплись вместе. А ещё переменная `i` никогда не примет значение 3, потому что длина `args` всего один элемент

Comment: Для сравнения: `alert(['Заголовок', '', ''].toString());`

Comment: Используйте `args.join('')` :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) возвращает массив значений. В данном случае

```
['Заголовок', '', '']
```

Далее этот массив передается параметром в метод `createModal`. Так как данный метод объявлен как `createModal(...args) {` параметры переданные в него собираются в массив `args`.

В данном случае массив `args` будет содержать только один элемент. Значение которого будет преобразовано в текст в строке

```
item.textContent = el;
```

на первой же итерации.

Это равносильно

```
item.textContent = ['Заголовок', '', ''].toString();
```

Вызов [`.toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Array/toString) для массива равносилен вызову [`.join(',')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Array/join), следовательно все элементы объединяются в строку с разделителем `,`. Так как два последних элемента - пустые строки, то в итоговой строке будут две запятые в конце, которые стоят перед первой постой строкой и перед второй.

Для исправления достаточно при вызове `createModal` добавить `spread operator`

```
super.createModal(...Object.values(this));
```

В этом случае массив `args` будет соответствовать массиву возвращаемому `Object.values(this)`.

Однако, стоит учитывать, что в текущем примере в этом массиве всего три элемента, а значит максимальный индекс `2`, следовательно условие `if (i === 3) {` всегда будет ложно.

А также это условие не гарантирует, что по указанному индексу будет именно поле, которое нужно вывести в виде разметки.

Для решения можно передавать не массив, а объект, и проверять поле по имени.